# retrieving headers / comment blocks

Tags: sed, processing

I have a number of log files that look like this:

```
/*
header
arbitrary number of lines
*/
blah blah
blah blah
```

Using simple Bash commands (preferably sed, not awk), how would I retrieve only the header lines (ideally including the comment markers)?

I've RTFM and tried googling, also found [some hints](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/sedoneliner.shtml), but not enough to get me started.

Thanks!

Comment: Another related link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sed-howto-remove-lines-paragraphs/

That does the opposite of what I need though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you confirm the following things, the script in this answer will work for you.

1. Files start with the "`/*`" characters

   - There may be multi-line C-Syntex comment block that is not nested
   - The comment block ends with no additional C-Statements on the same line

```
sed -n '/^\/\*/,/\*\// p' file.c
#        - - -    - -
```

This will match all lines from the start of the file to end of the comment block.
The second line (with a "`#`" in the start) highlights the match being searched for.
The "`-n`" at the start and the "`p`" at the end tell sed to print only the matching part.

Comment: @AnC, I think there is a problem in my solution too. It does not stop like `Richard`'s command after the first match! So, you'll get all the comments starting at new lines (requirement 1 is not limited to the start of the file) in a file.

Comment: Just realized that - so I'm now combining both of your solutions:

cat $LOGFILE | sed -e '/\*\//q' | sed -n '/^\/\*/,/\*\// p'

Sadly, I can't properly credit you both.

Comment: @AnC, you could do: `sed -n '/^\/*/,/*\// p' $LOGFILE | sed -e '/*\//q'` and skip the `cat`. But, I am not yet happy about it.

Answer (score 1):

This look at every file with an extension .log and if the first line is "/*" only, print everything until a line with "*/" only.

```
for file in *.log; do
      head -n1 $file | grep  -q '^/*' &&
      sed '/^\*\/$/q' $file; 
done
```

Comment: That does the job - thanks!

One caveat: It won't work if there's anything above the header, or if there a multiple comment blocks. However, I shouldn't worry about that until I actually need it.

Comment: And if there is no header, it will print the whole file!  There are a lot of failure modes.  Perhaps you can ask the question "How can I print comments in a file?" (And please let us use awk.)

Comment: You're right - nik's solution seems a little safer in that regard, so I'll use that for now.
Thanks again!

Comment: I have updated my answer to get rid of most of its worst problems.

Comment: Interesting approach. Now I'm torn between this and the combination of both of your solutions (see comments above)...

Comment: Both solutions have problems.  If either of them work for *your specific circumstances*, we got lucky.  If you want a more general solution, (cough)Perl(cough).  http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/File-Comments-0.07/lib/File/Comments.pm

Comment: You're right, for more complex tasks, a "proper" scripting language should be used.
Thanks for that link!

Answer (score 0):

```
cat *.log | sed -e 's/*\/\*//g' -e 's/\*\///g' >> smt.log
```

That might be it

Comment: I'm afraid that only removes the "*/" line. I've experimented with similar expressions, but didn't get anywhere - I think it's because sed works on a line-by-line basis.

Answer (score 0):

In case, if like me you stumbled across this question while trying to retrieve Doxygen style comments, the sed command is:

```
sed -n '/^\/\*/p; /^ \*/p' < file
```

For a more detailed explanation, I [blogged](http://www.serberus.net/2010/04/17/using-sed-to-parse-out-c-style-multiline-header-comments/) about it.